# How do I use Java streams to convert a set of strings to a set of maps?

Tags: java

Given a `Set<String>`, how do I use Java streams to create a `Set<Map>` where each string `s` becomes a map with a single key/value pair with key `"x"` and value `s`?

Something like this, but I need one more level of collect in there somewhere:
`set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(p->"x", v->v))`

Comment: Just one key/value pair per map in the set, @Eran.

Comment: What should the key for each value in the Set be? If all the values in the set should be inserted into the map with key as "x" then its not possible. As duplicate keys cannot be present.

Comment: @BandiKishore, the key should be the same string in each map, "x", but each string in the set is put in a separate map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Collections.singletonMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-) to map each `String` to a `Map<String,String>`. Then you can collect the `Map`s into a `Set` :

```
Set<Map<String,String>> mset = set.stream()
                                  .map(s -> Collections.singletonMap("x",s))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: That's beautiful! Thanks!